# Kibana not loading style sheets

Tags: angularjs, node.js, kibana, kibana-4

I am trying to build kibana 4.1 from the source.

I just downloaded the code using

```
git clone -b '4.1' 'https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git'
```

then installed all the dependancy using

```
sudo npm install
```

then i started the server using

```
npm start
```

kibana is loaded fine but it is loading any of the css files
I am getting 404 errors for all the style sheets

```
GET http://localhost:5601/styles/main.css?_b=@@buildNum 404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/visualize/styles/main.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/discover/styles/main.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/dashboard/styles/main.css 404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/settings/styles/main.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/collapsible_sidebar/collapsible_sidebar.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/typeahead/typeahead.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/markdown_vis/markdown_vis.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/metric_vis/metric_vis.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/plugins/table_vis/table_vis.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/doc_table/doc_table.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/visualize/visualize.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/doc_viewer/doc_viewer.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/agg_table/agg_table.css  404
GET http://localhost:5601/components/vislib/styles/main.css 404
```

Comment: I am getting 404 errors for all the style sheets

Comment: 404 file not found error.

Comment: just check whether you have all those files in the specified path

Comment: I think this issue is related to kibana or nodejs. these style sheets are dynamically created/parsed by the kibana

Comment: Yes, you are right! what is the version you installed? i am also running kibana 4, but aint facing any such issue

Comment: kibana version 4.1 cloned from the git source git clone -b '4.1' 'https://github.com/elastic/kibana.git'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run `grunt build` instead of `npm test` which in turn calls `grunt build` with several unnecessary test tasks.